# I cannot post process my output file .dat to .vtu (for Paraview) - Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, python, directory-structure

I'm new to understanding how Ubuntu works, I have managed to install a framework "TopOpt_in_PETSc_wrapped_in_Python" and PETSc on my ubuntu (via WSL).

The readme from:
https://github.com/thsmit/TopOpt_in_PETSc_wrapped_in_Python

suggests for post-processing I must:

*After solving the problem the output is written to a output.dat file. The designs can be viewed in Paraview (https://www.paraview.org/). To generate .vtu files from the output file use post_process_topopt.sh with Python 2 (with * the file path and name where the output file is stored):*

```
cd TopOpt_in_PETSc_wrapped_in_Python
./post_process_topopt.sh *
```

The file is located in the path:

```
/mnt/c/Users/asif1/Desktop/MSC/petsc-3.14.1/TopOpt_in_PETSc_wrapped_in_Python
```

name of my output file is:

```
output00000.dat
```

I've tried replacing the * with the filepath and filename.

However I believe my inexperience of Ubuntu is not allowing me to proceed with this, any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. It seems you may be using extremely old software or information. Your question has this info in it. post_process_topopt.sh with Python 2 . Python 2.0, documentation released on 16 October 2000. 22 years ago.

Comment: No worries David, I got it fixed! thanks for your response - It was Python 2.7 the framework used for post-processing. This software isn't too old, only a couple years :)